# Windows suddently disapearred from GRUB

Tags: linux, windows, boot, multi-boot, grub

I am using Windows 10 alongside with Ubuntu 19.04 Disco Dingo. Yesterday, I tried to start Windows 10 to play some games but it wasn't in the Grub's OS selection list.

I didn't touch anything on Grub configuration. It simply doesn't shows anymore. I tried to use some tools like boot-repair [from this website](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair). But no success until now.

I have this values on `fdisk -l` command:

```
Disco /dev/sda: 223,6 GiB, 240065183744 bytes, 468877312 setores
Disk model: SanDisk SSD PLUS
Unidades: setor de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamanho de setor (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamanho E/S (mínimo/ótimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tipo de rótulo do disco: gpt
Identificador do disco: 8DAC656D-1C58-453B-AAC0-CFF8433A090B

Dispositivo    Início       Fim   Setores Tamanho Tipo
/dev/sda1        2048   1023999   1021952    499M Windows ambiente de recuperação
/dev/sda2     1024000   1226751    202752     99M Sistema EFI
/dev/sda3     1226752   1259519     32768     16M Microsoft reservado
/dev/sda4     1259520 335339519 334080000  159,3G Microsoft dados básico
/dev/sda5   335544320 468875263 133330944   63,6G Linux sistema de arquivos
/dev/sda6   335339520 335544319    204800    100M BIOS inicialização
```

And this on `blkid`:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="RecuperaM-CM-'M-CM-#o" UUID="F6D8BCF7D8BCB6E9" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="3463a869-60f8-4d7f-a873-eb565125f18f"
/dev/sda2: UUID="E2BD-8AE2" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="4812631f-609c-4788-993d-7f914114d8d0"
/dev/sda4: UUID="FE5CCC8D5CCC425F" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="d70925fd-0806-4222-b7b4-45750fd26755"
/dev/sda5: UUID="b97d8af1-39bf-4206-a02c-c6deb73d6e68" TYPE="ext4" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="25beb09e-5c9a-4b76-b011-2f5759a3cfd0"
```

Please, is there anything that I can do or try to fix this problem?

Thank you.

**EDIT #1**

Hi. I tried to do as harrymc suggested, but it didn't work. I mounted all the sda# partitions and I ran the commands that he suggested. But Windows 10 doesn't appear on grub list during the boot.

When I run `sudo os-prober` nothing happens.

When running `update-grub` I get this result:

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Imagem Linux encontrada: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-25-generic
Imagem initrd encontrada: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-25-generic
Imagem Linux encontrada: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic
Imagem initrd encontrada: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic
erro: invalid volume.
grub-probe: erro: não foi possível encontrar uma unidade GRUB para /dev/sdb1. Verifique o seu device.map.
erro: invalid volume.
grub-probe: erro: não foi possível encontrar uma unidade GRUB para /dev/sdb2. Verifique o seu device.map.
erro: invalid volume.
grub-probe: erro: não foi possível encontrar uma unidade GRUB para /dev/sdb3. Verifique o seu device.map.
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
concluído
```

**EDIT #2**

I tried again mounting manually the other windows partitions. I got the following results:

```
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Argumento inválido
The device '/dev/sda3' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot into Linux and ensure that the Windows partition is mounted.

Run the following on the command line :

```
    sudo os-prober
```

If your Windows installation was found, run:

```
    sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Hi harrymc. Thank you for your answer. Please, could you check my Edits?

Comment: Try to use a Windows boot media to do Startup Repair, and see if it can locate the Windows installation (with UEFI this usually will not cause a problem with GRUB, but it may). If Windows is not detected, then there is a problem with its partition, which may require full installation.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't solve this problem without having to format and reinstall Windows. After that, I used a live Ubuntu ISO image and then I ran the commands that you suggested and now both OS are working. Thank you for your help harrymc

Comment: You on a roll plus some more there.... What is your profession?

Comment: At this time, I am working as an Junior System Analyst. But I could not solve this issue without reinstalling Windows. I did try with Windows Recovery CMD (FixBoot, FixMbr, RebuildBcd...) but no success too.. :/