# repair boot with encrypted partitions

Tags: multi-boot, luks, bootrepair

I am trying to repair my system boot with [boot-repair](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/).
I used to have a dual boot with Windows and Ubuntu and installed Manjaro alongside.
Unfortunately, Windows does no longer show in the boot menu.
I posted my boot info in [this paste](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/t6qZtYMmH9/).
When I installed Manjaro, I created two encrypted partitions. Boot-repair has the following warnings:

> - LegacyWindows detected. You may want to retry after deactivating the separate /boot/efi partition
> - You may want to retry after mounting your encrypted partitions

I don't understand if and how I should deactivate the separate /boot/efi partition and how to handle the encrypted partitions.

I mounted my encrypted Manjaro partition, i.e. `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p10 manjaro` and then `sudo mount /dev/mapper/manjaro /mnt/manjaro`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How old is your backup?

Comment: I backed up my system before I installed Manjaro, both creating a snapshot with clonezilla and a data backup with borg.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows suddently disapearred from GRUB](https://superuser.com/questions/1471629/windows-suddently-disapearred-from-grub)

Comment: @harrymc Unfortunately not, os-prober does not output anything

Comment: Try [Rescatux & Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/).

Comment: To repair the windows boot loader, I found [this](https://woshub.com/how-to-repair-uefi-bootloader-in-windows-8/) article helpful. A live windows usb is used to restore the relevant files.

Comment: @Zuabi I am having a similar problem right now, would you mind sharing your solution if you found one?

Comment: @tai, unfortunately I never directly solved the issue. I simply reverted my system back using the snapshots I had done previously.